# Bluetooth low energy devices require to write firmware / drivers?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, microcontroller

I have a Bluetooth Low energy device (BLE) device from Nordic nRF52811, this is complete soC contains the controller as well.

I need to use its Bluetooth only, then whatever I receive "DATA" on its Bluetooth module I need to transfer it to another Microcontroller outside its module

My question is: does this BLE module contains the firmware for Bluetooth, and microcontroller or do I need to write it separately? Like, the driver for BLE, SPI interface ?

Comment: usually two possible solutions there either you write code on the same device with the bluetooth and you have to have code, driver if you will, to talk to that peripheral and make it work.  Or you put generic code that creates a ble module if you will then you need another mcu or master/host to talk to the module in whatever protocol is provided, which also implies a driver if you will.  driver just being, usually a small, amount of code that makes the desired features work.  some setup and some reading and writing of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nRF52 chips normally come with the flash completely empty, without firmware. You can find software and guides at Nordic Semiconductor's website.